# Run batch file in the background

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file, this batch file will not start automatically, it will only run when i double click on it.
Can I run the batch file in the background when I double click on it.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can start it minimized with `start`, if that is enough. Really hiding it is difficult (although I can think of an option right now).

Basically you need to determine whether the batch has been started by double-clicking it. You can do this by defining a special variable and look for it:

```
@echo off
if not defined FOO (
  set FOO=1
  start /min "" %~0
  exit /b
)

rem here whatever you wanted to do originally in the batch
```

As long as the `FOO` variable isn't defined (which is probably the default almost everywhere), this batch will launch itself minimized again, but *with* the variable defined first. Environments are passed to subprocesses, which is why this works.

Comment: This is my favorite method.  I love this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you would generally need something else to run the script in that manor
i.e.
Create a shortcut, and set the “Run” field for the shortcut to “Minimized’.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click or tab away from the cmd.exe window that the batch file is running it, it's "in the background" -- I'm not really sure what you want but it sounds like you might be asking how to run the batch file without displaying the cmd.exe window.

If so I can think of two ways: first, you can create a shortcut to the batch file, right click it, and in the properties there set the shortcut to run minimized (should be a drop down option next to Run).

You can also wrap invocation of the batch file in a VBScript file using Windows Script Host's shell object ([calling the Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx)) to run the batch file invisibly. Passing 0 as the intWindowStyle parameter will suppress display of a window or anything.

Answer (score 1):

@Ghyath Serhal
I have used [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) to do this on another program, it is an external application that can be used to modify the command prompt. To use it, you will need to either enter this code (see below) into it's own batch file, or into the command prompt, where it will run 'BatchFile.bat' with a hidden terminal window. I haven't found a way to use this in a single batch file, but I only found out about this today.

`cmdow /run /hid 'BatchFile.bat'`

Hope this helps.