# How to start a batch file minimized in a Windows CE device (using another batch or shortcut)?

Tags: windows-mobile, batch-file, windows-ce, batch-processing

I have a batch file which is running on a Windows CE 5 device (for being accurate, Motorola MK3000). The batch file installs some CAB files and finally starts an exe.
e.g.

```
@ECHO OFF
wceload /noaskdest /delete 0 myPath\myCab.cab
START myPath\myApp.exe
```

Now, I want it to run in minimized mode (not displaying the white command window).
As far as I can see, a shortcut can't be used for that purpose as the "Run as Minimized" option is not available on the device's shortcuts (unlike shortcuts on the PC).
I've tried to use another batch file to start my batch with "/min" argument:

```
@echo off
start /min path\myBat.bat
```

but it appears not to be calling my batch at all (without the "/min" it does call it...).

I've also tried the "define variable" approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666433/run-batch-file-in-the-background/4666485#4666485) but can't run it on the device (it cries about the brackets).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

use

```
  start /B  path\myBat.bat
```

to start the new session in the background.