# Is it possible to run a python program in the shell from the windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, command-prompt, python-idle

What I am trying to do is to make a start-up application in batch for a python program. At the moment, it launches into the windows command prompt (using `python [ProgramName] %*`), I don't mind this happening, but I would rather it launched into the IDLE shell instead. This is purely for appearance reasons (sorry, forgot the word that would fit best instead of 'appearance', I know it begins with a 't', but I'll edit it in when I remember), basically because it has some inbuilt colour schemes instead.

I have been Googling this for ages, but can't seem to find an answer, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `python -m idlelib [ProgramName]` will open the file in idle... give me a moment to figure out how to execute instead of open for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start idle executing a file you can use:

```
python -m idlelib -r [ProgramFile]

                  ^ not sure why this is -r but it executes a file.
        ^ start idlelib module
```

however this is not the true idle application but an instance of python running idlelib (may call the process python insstead of IDLE) so you can use `-r` flag with the IDLE executable instead:

```
/PATH/TO/IDLE.exe -r [ProgramFile]
```

I have not tested this on windows but was able to do equivalent thing on my mac.

Comment: Thanks, this ran the program in the IDLE shell, but it opened up a blank command window behind it, is there a way of closing that? I've tried using `pythonw -m idlelib -r [ProgramName]` but that didn't affect it

Comment: that would be the batch file that starts idle. Batch files are not really my area of expertise but I think you want to look at [Run batch file in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666433/run-batch-file-in-the-background).

Comment: I've just finished fixing the hiding the command window, I've done it using cndow `cmdow /run /hid [ProgramName]`

Comment: @sonrad10 if using `cmdow` lets you run a batch file in the background you might consider posting an answer to [Run batch file in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666433/run-batch-file-in-the-background).

Comment: @TadhgMcDolaldJensin Ok, I'll do that